# Central Limit Theorem: Show that $\mathrm{Pois}(n)$ distribution if approximately Normal if $n$ is a large positive integer

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Here is what the solution in the textbook says:

> Let $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$, with $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ i.i.d. $\sim \mathrm{Pois}(1)$. Then $S_n \sim\mathrm{Pois}(n)$ and for $n$ large, $S_n$ is approximately $N(n,n)$ by the CLT.

Based on my understanding of the Central Limit Theorem, $\overline{S}_n$ is approximately $N(n,n)$, not $S_n$. Here is my proof:

> The Central Limit Theorem says
>   \begin{align}
> \sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\overline{S}_n-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathcal{N}(0,1) \\
> \sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\overline{S}_n-n}{n}\right)\xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathcal{N}(0,1) \\
> \end{align}
>
> With a location scale transformation we get:
>
> \begin{align}
> \overline{S}_n-n \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathcal{N}(0,n) \\
> \overline{S}_n \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathcal{N}(n,n) \\
> \end{align}
>
> And since $\overline{S}_n=\frac{1}{n}S_n$,  $S_n  \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathcal{N}(n,n^3)$.

Is my proof incorrect or is the problem just a difference in notation?

Comment: One really should wonder what assertions that some sequence of objects converges to $\mathcal{N}(0,n)$ or to $\mathcal{N}(n,n)$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$ could even *mean*. A limit cannot depend on $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mean and standard deviation of a single summand are $1$, not $n$, so you have just $\sqrt{n}\left(\overline{S}_n-1\right)$ going to $N(0,1)$, which is consistent with the desired statement.

That said, the CLT does not *really* say things like "$S_n$ is approximately $N(n,n)$". It only *really* describes about shifted+rescaled distributions converging to *fixed* normal distributions.